# jQuery - Finding certain element before line of code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have come across different solutions to my problem (e.g. [here](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjn3fHg6tfNAhUmDsAKHR0ABZYQFggrMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F7018337%2Ffind-closest-previous-element-jquery&usg=AFQjCNEE9W4AsEU3nO11pexaDrpdnMvtRw)) on how to find a particular element, but it doesn't seem to be directly applicable to me.

What I am trying to do is use jQuery to locate a particular  tag that exists above the elements clicked on to activate the function. The plan is to retrieve the text from it.

Here is my code.

```js
$(".fixture-deletion-text, .fixture-deletion-logo").on('click', function() {
  //$(this).prev("h3").text()
  //$("#me").closest("h3 + div").prev().find('span b')
  console.log($(this).closest(".row").prev().find("h3").text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="small-12 medium-4 columns">
    <h3>Fixture #1</h3>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="small-12 medium-4 columns">
    <label>Date and Time
      <input readonly type="text" class="span2 dpt" name="match-dt[]" value="02-12-1989 12:05">
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="small-12 medium-3 columns">
    <label>Team
      <select name="team-division[]">
        <option value="team-1">1st Team</option>
        <option value="team-2">2nd Team</option>
      </select>
      <div class="error-box"></div>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="small-12 medium-3 columns">
    <label>Competition
      <input id="competition-input" name="competition[]" type="text" />
      <div id="competition-error" class="error-box"></div>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="small-12 medium-2 columns">
    <label>Home/Away
      <select name="location[]">
        <option value="home">Home</option>
        <option value="away">Away</option>
      </select>
      <div class="error-box"></div>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="small-12 medium-6 columns">
    <label>Opponents
      <input id="opposition-input" name="opposition[]" type="text" />
      <div id="opposition-error" class="error-box"></div>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="small-12 medium-6 columns">
    <label>Venue
      <input id="venue-input" name="venue[]" type="text" />
      <div id="venue-error" class="error-box"></div>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="small-12 columns end">
    <img src="images/delete-icon.png" class="fixture-deletion-logo float-right" />
    <a class="fixture-deletion-text float-right">Delete Fixture</a>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="small-12 medium-4 columns">
      <h3>Fixture #1</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="small-12 medium-4 columns">
      <label>Date and Time
        <input readonly type="text" class="span2 dpt" name="match-dt[]" value="02-12-1989 12:05">
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="small-12 medium-3 columns">
      <label>Team
        <select name="team-division[]">
          <option value="team-1">1st Team</option>
          <option value="team-2">2nd Team</option>
        </select>
        <div class="error-box"></div>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="small-12 medium-3 columns">
      <label>Competition
        <input id="competition-input" name="competition[]" type="text" />
        <div id="competition-error" class="error-box"></div>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="small-12 medium-2 columns">
      <label>Home/Away
        <select name="location[]">
          <option value="home">Home</option>
          <option value="away">Away</option>
        </select>
        <div class="error-box"></div>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="small-12 medium-6 columns">
      <label>Opponents
        <input id="opposition-input" name="opposition[]" type="text" />
        <div id="opposition-error" class="error-box"></div>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="small-12 medium-6 columns">
      <label>Venue
        <input id="venue-input" name="venue[]" type="text" />
        <div id="venue-error" class="error-box"></div>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="test"></div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="small-12 columns end">
      <img src="images/delete-icon.png" class="fixture-deletion-logo float-right" />
      <a class="fixture-deletion-text float-right">Delete Fixture</a>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="small-12 medium-4 columns">
        <h3>Fixture #1</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="small-12 medium-4 columns">
        <label>Date and Time
          <input readonly type="text" class="span2 dpt" name="match-dt[]" value="02-12-1989 12:05">
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="small-12 medium-3 columns">
        <label>Team
          <select name="team-division[]">
            <option value="team-1">1st Team</option>
            <option value="team-2">2nd Team</option>
          </select>
          <div class="error-box"></div>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="small-12 medium-3 columns">
        <label>Competition
          <input id="competition-input" name="competition[]" type="text" />
          <div id="competition-error" class="error-box"></div>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="small-12 medium-2 columns">
        <label>Home/Away
          <select name="location[]">
            <option value="home">Home</option>
            <option value="away">Away</option>
          </select>
          <div class="error-box"></div>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="small-12 medium-6 columns">
        <label>Opponents
          <input id="opposition-input" name="opposition[]" type="text" />
          <div id="opposition-error" class="error-box"></div>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="small-12 medium-6 columns">
        <label>Venue
          <input id="venue-input" name="venue[]" type="text" />
          <div id="venue-error" class="error-box"></div>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="test"></div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="small-12 columns end">
        <img src="images/delete-icon.png" class="fixture-deletion-logo float-right" />
        <a class="fixture-deletion-text float-right">Delete Fixture</a>
      </div>
```

I based the jQuery example on the link above, but it dosen't work. Here's how it goes: If the user were to click on the *fixture-deletion-text/fixture-deletion-logo*, the code would find the very next  element **above** that particular clicked element. From there, I can figure out how to delete that particular fixture.

Comment: Can you reduce your HTML to the absolute minimum, and add comment (in the HTML) to show which deletion element should be clicked, and which element should be deleted/removed? I can't work out what you mean by "*the very next element **above** that particular...element*" should it be the parent element? The previous sibling element? Another element entirely?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to put a div element as a parent of a whole block:

```
<div class="fixture">
    <!--fixture code-->
</div>
```

And then with jquery using selector for closest fixture element:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fixture-deletion-text, .fixture-deletion-logo").on('click', function() {
        $(this).closest(".fixture").remove();
    });
});
```

[Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/bv8UmlLI3BRZx12XCJhT?p=preview) you have a working example

Comment: Works great. Thanks!